# Default Midnight Commander key binding for "change-directory"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding, midnight-commander

What is the default key binding in `Midnight Commander` to open a dialog box asking for the target directory ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used it, but try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: ... or the alternative shortcut <esc><c> (meaning: press and release the "Esc"-key and press "c" afterwards. Use <alt-tab> (or <esc><tab>) and <ctrl-p> / <ctrl-n> for path completion

Comment: [Esc]+[c] is that I was looking for. Thank you. This should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> and it works.